# How to rename values that match with another values using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following  dataframe:

```r
df <- structure(list(x1 = 2:5, x2 = c("zz", "333.iv", "333.i.v", "333(100ug)"
)), .Names = c("x1", "x2"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df
#>   x1         x2
#> 1  2         zz
#> 2  3     333.iv
#> 3  4    333.i.v
#> 4  5 333(100ug)
```

For column `x2`, what I want to do is to rename all values with `333` into 
`3-33` resulting in:

```r
   x1         x2
   2          zz
   3        3-33
   4        3-33
   5        3-33
```

How can I do that?

Comment: df$x2 <- ifelse(grepl("333", df$x2), "3-33", df$x2)

Comment: Beware that `grepl('333', '43332')` matches the substring.  So you need `...fixed=TRUE)` or else `'^333$'`

Comment: @smci -  `grepl('333', '43332', fixed=TRUE)` matches the substring too.

Comment: ...and if you're going to do `grepl("^text$", x)` just do `x=="text"` instead

Comment: @smci, add `fixed = TRUE` is to improve speed in this case. They gives the same results but it is faster with `fixed = TRUE`.

Comment: @thelatemail: we wouldn't do `x=="pattern"` , obviously, if pattern had any special chars. Anyway my point to the OP was the accepted answer is a little sloppy in also matching substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
df$x2[grepl('333', df$x2, fixed = TRUE)] <- '3-33'
# > df
# x1   x2
# 1  2   zz
# 2  3 3-33
# 3  4 3-33
# 4  5 3-33
```

With `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
    mutate(x2 = ifelse(grepl('333', x2, fixed = TRUE), '3-33', x2))
```